# SQL-Server importing XML - time in wrong timezone

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I am having an issue with xml import through SSIS package. I am importing data to SQL Server table successfully however i noticed that my time is being imported wrongly. Here is how the xml file looks like:

[image]

And this is what i get in SQL table:

[image]

Now i see that time zone is set as America/Los_Angeles and i see that the time is shifted somehow for 7h. 
My SSIS package simply read the value "From" and "To" and pass that value into table as datetime type. I haven not done any data conversion in here nor i included timezone anywhere. What it seems to me is that time somehow is being converted on its own to some timezone when i push it to the table.

I tried googling this but i cant figure out what is going on and why. I was under impression that when i read the value and just send it to the table as is it will be written as value SSIS read from xml. 
Any idea?

Comment: Something is happening in whatever is importing it that converts it to UTC timezone (+0 instead of -8).

Comment: Which system time settings, timezone are set on your server?